# Why does proposed `std::shared_ptr::operator[]` take `std::ptrdiff_t` as an argument

Tags: c++, c++17

[According to the N4562 proposal, the newly proposed `std::shared_ptr::operator[]` takes in `std::ptrdiff_t`, which is a signed type](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2015/n4562.html#memory.smartptr.shared.obs).

This is inconsistent with every indexing operator in standard library. Even `std::unique_ptr::operator[]` takes `std::size_t`.

What's the rationale for this decision?

Comment: Maybe because the committee finally acknowledges that using a unsigned type as a index was a horrible mistake and they are trying to change it on the new stuff?

Comment: And why exactly is that a mistake? For instance, makes perfect sense with `std::vector`.

Comment: @bipll the fact the trying to iterate backwards is a pain is a good start.  intuitively you would want to write `for(auto i = cont.size() - 1; i > 0; --i)` but you can't as it will never be less than 0.

Comment: I was going to guess that because you can alias `shared_ptr`'s, unlike other containers your `shared_ptr` could actually point to the middle of an array, and negative indexing might make sense. But they actually require the index be positive, so there's no purpose in using a signed type here. It seems like just a poor decision.

Comment: Intuitively I would always write `for(auto i(cont.rbegin())` in such a case.

Comment: @GManNickG A poor decision is to use unsigned to represent positive only; that's *not* what unsigned means. Unsigned means modular arithmetic. Unless your domain is well modeled by modular arithmetic, you should not use unsigned*. This is why the entire committee thinks that despite indices to vectors never being being negative, making them unsigned was *still* a mistake. * or if you want to treat the integer as a collection of bits.

Comment: @NirFriedman, "Unsigned means modular arithmetic", gonna need a citation on that.

Comment: @FatihBAKIR: That is what unsigned is defined to be, operations on unsigned integers are modulo `2^N`. This is why assigning `-1` gives the highest value.

Comment: @NirFriedman: I've never bought that argument. Yes, unsigned are not "the natural numbers", but signed isn't "the integers" either. *Both* types have "unexpected" behavior if you're not willing to actually learn what they mean. Unsigned types better approximate the type I'd like to use, so I use it. If the caller can't be arsed to learn the language, not my problem, not going to make it my problem.

Comment: @GManNickG, just because you can use it that way, doesn't mean you cannot use it for other purposes, such as indexing. Also, you've just assumed two's complement, which the standard doesn't guarantee. If your machine uses one's complement for example, you wouldn't get the highest value.

Comment: @FatihBAKIR: Please go read existing SO questions on the matter. I **did not** assume 2-s compliment. Unsigned is **defined** as modular arithmetic, the bit representation of the values is a whole different matter. Again, please do some research before you reply. I'm extremely well-aware the standard doesn't mandate 2's compliment. You are **guaranteed** that `unsigned i = -1;` gives the highest representable value of `unsigned`, regardless of bit representation.

Comment: @GManNickG, Well just checked the standard and yeah I didn't realise the signed to unsigned conversion didn't rely on directly copying the bit pattern! Sorry about that.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/125141/discussion-between-gmannickg-and-fatih-bakir).

Comment: @NathanOliver That's less a problem with `unsigned` types themselves, and more a problem with people not being educated on the differences between them and `signed` types.  Although, `for(auto i = cont.size() - 1, lim = cont.size(); i < lim; --i)` is indeed less intuitive...

Comment: `for (auto i = cont.size(); i--; )` has always served me fine, I don't see how people get so confused about the issue...

Answer (score 1):

Probably this should be pointer interface unification. Good ol' C pointers when used as arrays accept negative indices: `p[-2]` is the same as `*(p - 2)`; and `ptrdiff_t` is thus naturally signed.

Comment: "Requires: `get() != 0 && i >= 0`" You can't pass a negative index anyway.

Comment: I thought so too, but I doubt it - we have a precedence with `std::unique_ptr` which takes an unsigned integer.

Comment: Then it looks like a proposal inconsistency.

Comment: @GManNickG That seems like an unnecessary restriction.  You can use the aliasing constructor to get a pointer to the middle of an array.  `ptr[-2]` would make sense in that case.

Comment: @GManNickG With a custom deleter on the `shared_ptr`, it's perfectly reasonable to pass `new int[n] + 1`, and index the `shared_ptr` with `[-1]` IMO. I'm not sure why it forbids negative indices

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb: Yeah, that's what I'm saying. They were close to having a useful utility, but then banned it. So you're left with a type where half the range is disallowed.

Comment: The question "Why use a type that allows me to encounter an error?" is the same question we always hear. If you pass a `-1` it's always an error, whether or not the `shared_ptr` uses `int` or `unsigned`. So the question really should not say "that allows me to encounter an error", but the question should be "Why use a type that allows me to *discover* an error that I encountered?". That's why `int` is superior </signed-vs-unsigned>.

Comment: @TavianBarnes: Are you disagreeing with me or adding additional commentary? I already addressed this in the comments on the question.